# SKNode.removeFromParent() EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcode6-beta6

I noticed a weird behavior in my Swift project and reproduced it on a empty SpriteKit Project that way:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
        self.addChild(sprite)
        //sprite.removeFromParent()

        let sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
        self.addChild(sprite2)
        sprite2.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

It crash before the app start and all I can see is this :
[image: Screenshot of xCode]

My config is xCode6-Beta6, iPad Mini Retina with iOS8-Beta5 and OSX 10.9.4.
I also reproduced the bug in the simulators; with xCode6-Beta5; and moving the code in `touchesBegan` method

Uncommenting the line `sprite.removeFromParent()` make the bug disappear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**IMPORTANT:** this bug has been corrected since iOS 8.1, be sure to update AND make your app unavailable for iOS 8.0 and prior.

I found out what happens... and it should be some Apple employe which did a mistake. Explainations :

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
self.addChild(sprite)

let sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
self.addChild(sprite2)
sprite2.removeFromParent()

println( sprite == sprite2 ) // Returns "true"
// Then crash
```

And if you do it :

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
sprite.name = "1"
self.addChild(sprite)

let sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
sprite2.name = "2"
self.addChild(sprite2)
sprite2.removeFromParent()

println( sprite == sprite2 ) // Returns "false"
// Then all is right, no crash
```

I think very simply when you call `.removeFromParent()` Apple's code check for equality in code with `==` like they would do in *Objective-C*. But since it's *Swift* you should do `===` to check for **object equality** rather than `==`, so a dumb mistake.

Congratz you found a bug in SpriteKit Code, [go fill a form at Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) :D

Comment: I see .. I'll just name all my nodes then! Thank you

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. I'm running into this bug too.

Answer (score 0):

This happen only when SKNode have same name and same class.  Set to SKNode unique name.

My Code:
- (void) removeItemWithIdentifier:(FoodsIdentifiers) identifier{

```
NSArray *items = [foodItemHolderNode children];
int count = (int)[items count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    FoodItemObject *foodItem = [items objectAtIndex:i];
    int itemID = [[foodItem.objectDictionary objectForKey:FOODITEM_IDENTIFIER_KEY] intValue];

    if (itemID == identifier) {
        [foodItem removeFromParent];
        break;
    }

}

// NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID%i", (int)identifier];
//SKNode *item = [foodItemHolderNode childNodeWithName:name];
//[item removeFromParent];
```

**warning REMOVE FROM PARENT WITH SAME NAME BUG!!!!!!!!**

Comment: Yeah logic, same name, so comparison give same result